# google map api does not load when script in on same html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

There might be simple reason, but I am not getting it, so here I ask -

1. I am using google map in simple way in my simple html site as instructed on https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map
   and
   http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_basic.asp
   , where google map script src ( src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" , which I have tried with key and without key) and initialize() and addDomListener on load function are on same page, and I save that page with .html extension (tried with .php on wamp too).
2. However map does not show up, so then I put the initialize() and addDomListener function in different wrapper like map_script.js and called it on main .html or index.php page, then only map was shown on page.
3. Is it because html or php couldn't process that js part, and it worked when it was in different js wrapper. Or Is there something else?

Comment: What does _your_ code look like?

Comment: Both the examples you reference work for me [google example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_simpleMap.html), [w3schools example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_w3schoolsEx_simpleMap.html), the only modification was to remove the key from the w3schools example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

try this script

Comment: I understood the difference... In those tutorials var map= new google..etc is used, while in yours var map is declared outside initialize function, which is how I was using in .js wrapper.Now its working in same page, May there is difference in api version and tutorials are on old one. Thanks man!

Comment: @amitfreeman: The "difference" will not make any difference with the code in the answer, the result will be the same also with `var map= new google.....` . There must have been something else wrong with your code(we'll never know what, unless you show us your code)